# Proving that $rank(A) + rank(B) - n \le rank(AB)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to demonstrate the following statement:

If $\ A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\ B \in M_{n,t}(\mathbb{R})$ show that:
$$
rank(A)+
 rank(B) -n \ \le \ rank(AB) \ \le  \ \min\{rank(A), rank(B)\}
$$

So far I've only managed to show the second inequality (I think), because $rank(A) \ge rank(AB)$ and $rank(B) \ge rank(AB)$. I don't know how to approach the first one. It could probably be interpreted using dimensions of images and matrices of linear applications, but then I can't figure out what $n$ corresponds to.

Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
rank(A) + rank(B) \le rank\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ -I_n & B \end{pmatrix} = rank\begin{pmatrix}0 & AB \\ -I_n & 0 \end{pmatrix} = rank(AB) + n
$$

Can you find the transform that turns $\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ -I_n & B \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & AB \\ -I_n & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: can you please tell the transmission that you used ?

Comment: @neelkanth
$$
\begin{pmatrix} I & A \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ -I & B \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} I & B \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & AB \\ -I & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Thank you ......